# bokeh 0.5.1 abnormal operation

Tags: python, histogram, bokeh

I use the bokeh source code. version is 0.5.1

source code is in the bokeh homepage, source code is histogram

but not operation,

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import scipy.special
from bokeh.plotting import *

mu, sigma = 0, 0.5

measured = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
hist, edges = np.histogram(measured, density=True, bins=50)

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
pdf = 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2*np.pi)) * np.exp(-(x-mu)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
cdf = (1+scipy.special.erf((x-mu)/np.sqrt(2*sigma**2)))/2

output_file('histogram.html')

hold()

figure(title="Normal Distribution (횓쩌=0, 횕혘=0.5)",tools="previewsave",
       background_fill="#E8DDCB")
quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], fill_color="#036564", line_color="#033649")


show()
```

---

compile error --->

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\workspace\python\anaconda\test\temp1.py", line 22, in 
    quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], fill_color="#036564", line_color="#033649")
  File "C:\Users\junseok\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting.py", line 336, in wrapper
    retval = func(curdoc(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\junseok\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh_glyph_functions.py", line 54, in func
    y_data_fields = [ glyph_params[yy]['field'] for yy in yfields if glyph_params[yy]['units'] == 'data' ]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Answer (score 0):

Hi this change in this example got checked in just slightly too early. The problem is the `bottom=0`. That now works on master, but it was not changed yet for the release, so the example should not have been changed yet, either. For all of those, you just need to pass a full actual list of zeros:

```
quad(top=hist, bottom=np.zeros_like(hist), left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], fill_color="#036564", line_color="#033649")
```

This nicer, simpler `bottom=0` syntax will be in a 0.5.2 release in a few weeks as well as any intervening dev releases on Binstar.